# Attempting to create an issue with JIRA REST API results in a 500 error

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

For automation purposes I'm trying to create issues through the JIRA REST API, but I'm getting a 500, Internal Server Exception as response without any additional information.

With the Chrome-plugin "advance REST client", I ran through the following steps:

1. Entered the endpoint: h.ttps://[company-jira-url]/rest/api/2/issue/
2. Set the HTTP method: POST
3. Added the required headers:

   - Content-Type: application/json
   - Authorization: Basic    (100% sure this one's correct)
4. Added the json payload (Basically the minimum required fields):

   > ```
   > {
   > "fields": {
   >    "project": 
   >    { 
   >      "key": "HACK"
   >    },
   >    "summary": "REST EXAMPLE",
   >    "description": "Creating an issue via REST API",
   >    "issuetype": {
   >       "name": "Bug"
   >    }
   >   }
   > }
   > ```
5. Click "Send"

The request basically looks like this (base64 string is not correct in this example):

[The Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WMJ1.png)

Result:

[The Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YN0t.png)

Anyone ?

Comment: deleted, just saw its in teh cloud.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure that your JSON is valid as a JIRA REST API request.

Comment: @Koshinae : It should be ok, I've checked which fields are mandatory in JIRA, and only used the ones as displayed above...
Also it's almost an exact copy-paste request from the JIRA documentation...
--If it wasn't for the "cloud", what did you respond in you first reply? (could possibly help)

Comment: That look into the logfiles :) The exception message tells what does it miss form the JSON.

Comment: Also, do you have mandatory/required customfields?

Comment: Try createmeta to have a list of what can/should be set. I would start with giving and `id` instead of `key` in "project".

Comment: Ok, apparently our Jira is hosted by ourselves. I checked it an I got a stack trace:

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30411.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.common.interceptor.impl.DispatchProviderHelper$ResponseOutInvoker$1.invoke(DispatchProviderHelper.java:234)
 ......

Can't really identify the problem here...

Comment: @Koshinae: I checked the createmeta and I think I've set it up right. 
I also tried using IDs instead of the "KEY" values, but without any success.

Comment: What JIRA version are you using and which JAVA version is it hosted on? I had similar problems (500s for no clear reason) when I was using a Java JDK version incompatibile with my JIRA. In my case it was Jira 6.4 vs JDK 1.8.25 incompatibility: https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/supported-platforms-207488170.html